# Close Modal Only When Authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

In order to create a transaction the user must first be authenticated(password) in the confirm dialog modal. Once the user is authenticated the modal is closed and the transaction is shown. If a user is not authenticated correctly the modal still closes and a toast message is displayed with the error. I would like to change this logic so that the user must re-enter the password if their attempt was not authenticated.

setting the state inside createTransaction is done in an async way. this.closeModal in newTransactionModal is whats causing the modal to be closed and the state to be reset.

NewTransactionModal.js

```
this.state.showConfirmDialog ? (
                        <ConfirmDialog
                            type="New Transaction"
                            onPasswordChange={this.changePassword}
                            onConfirm={this.handleCreateClick}
                            onCancel={this.handleClose}
                            errMsg = {this.props.passwordErrMsg}
                        />
                    ) : null
```

NewTransactionModal.js

```
handleCreateClick = () => {
        if (this.formIsValid()) {        
            let path = '/transaction',
                transaction = {
                    type: this.state.transactionType.id,
                    amount: this.state.transactionAmount,
                    internalComment: this.state.comment,
                    userPassword: this.state.password
                },
                extraDataForError = {
                    typeName: this.state.transactionType.name,
                    advertiserName: this.state.advertiser.name,
                    fundingType: this.state.advertiser.fundingType,
                    financialDocumentId: this.state.documentId,
                    financialDocumentType: this.state.document && this.state.document.documentMetadata.documentType
                };

            if (this.state.transactionType.creditType) {
                path += '/transfer';
                transaction.debitAdvertiserId = this.state.advertiserId;
                transaction.creditAdvertiserId = this.state.transferAdvertiserId;
                transaction.debitFinancialDocumentId = this.state.documentId;
                transaction.creditFinancialDocumentId = this.state.documentId;
            } else {
                transaction.advertiserId = this.state.advertiserId;
                transaction.financialDocumentId = this.state.documentId;
            }

            this.props.createTransaction(path, transaction, extraDataForError);                

            this.closeModal();

        }
    };
```

ListTransaction.js

```
createTransaction = (path, data, extra) => {
        const failureMsg = 'Failed to create transaction';

        if (!path || !data) {
            this.setState({
                toastMessage: failureMsg,
                toastType: 'error'
            });
            return;
        }

        const getErrTransactions = res => {
            return [{ transaction: {...data, ...extra}, validations: res.validations, result: res.result }];
        };

        this.setState({ toastType: 'pending' }, async () => {
            try {
                const res = await ApiService.post(path, data, this.abortController.signal);
                if (res && res.result !== 'FAILURE') {
                    this.setState({
                        toastMessage: 'Transaction created',
                        toastType: 'success',
                        selected: []
                    }, () => this.loadData(1));
                } else if (res) {
                    this.handleError(getErrTransactions(res), failureMsg);
                } else {
                    this.setState({toastType: null})               
                }
            } catch (err) {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
                        return false;
                    } else if (err.json) {
                        this.setState({
                            passwordErrMsg: "Please enter a valid password"
                        })
                        const jsonErr = await err.json();
                        this.handleError(jsonErr.result ? getErrTransactions(jsonErr) : jsonErr, failureMsg);
                    } else {
                        this.handleError(err, failureMsg);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.setState({ toastType: null });
                }
            }            
        });
    };
```

ListTransactions.js

```
canCreate ? (
                        <NewTransactionModal
                            show={showNewTransactionModal}
                            types={allowedTransactionTypes}
                            createTransaction={this.createTransaction}
                            passwordErrMsg = {this.state.passwordErrMsg}
                            handlePasswordAttempt = {this.handlePasswordAttempt}
                            handleRecent={this.handleRecent}
                            handleClose={this.hideModal}
                        />
                    ) : null
```

I expect that that the user must still enter their password after an invalid attempt and that the modal does not go away. Also after the user has entered the correct password than the modal is closed.

Comment: What are you using to manage the authenticated state?

Comment: Nothing at the moment. Hitting confirm on the modal would just exit the modal regardless of password being incorrect or not.